# Build method in JPA with composite key

Tags: jpa, composite-key

This is my entity with composite key:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "course_ratings")
public class CourseRating {
    @EmbeddedId
    private CourseRatingKey id;
}
```

Where `CourseRatingKey` looks like this:

```
@Embeddable
public class CourseRatingKey implements Serializable {
    @Column(name = "user_id")
    private int userId;

    @Column(name = "course_id")
    private int courseId;

    public CourseRatingKey() {
    }
    
    // getters, setters, equals(), hashCode()
}
```

And my JPA repository

```
@Repository
public interface CourseRatingRepository extends JpaRepository<CourseRating, CourseRatingKey> {

}
```

I am trying to build method that will return list of all `CourseRating` with given `courseId` property of `CourseRatingKey`. Below method doesn't work because JPA doesn't recognize it:

```
repository.findAllByIdCourseId(int id);
```

How can I build my method name to achieve my goal?

Comment: Hey, what error message are you getting?
I checked in my project and both solutions worked for me:

List<CourseRating> findAllByIdCourseId(Long id)
List<CourseRating> findAllByCourseId(Long id)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved my problem by declaring this method in repository. I'm a bit confused as the other methods work without declaring.

```
@Repository
public interface CourseRatingRepository extends JpaRepository<CourseRating, CourseRatingKey> {

    List<CourseRating> findAllByIdCourseId(Integer id);
}
```